# How to get the size of the file in a server using NSURLRequest in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, download

There is an image file in the server. I would like to know the size of the image without downloading it from the server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386990/get-size-file-nsurlconnection look at this

Comment: You need to make a `HEAD` type request to the URL and read the `Content-Length` key-value from the response headers. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19317092/1407017)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find size of a file before downloading it in iOS 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315533/how-to-find-size-of-a-file-before-downloading-it-in-ios-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to do a HEAD request instead of a GET request. Then you'll check the Content-Length to get the size.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];  
[request setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];  
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
       NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;

    NSLog(@"Size: %@", [[httpResponse allHeaderFields] objectForKey:@"Content-Length"]);
}];
```

Note that `[[response allHeaderFields] objectForKey:@"Content-Length"]` will return either an NSNumber or an NSString, not a primitive (I'm not sure which, you'll have to test it, or maybe someone else can comment on that).

**Update**

`[response expectedContentLength]` is an easier way to get the content length once you've made the request. And that one returns a `long long` instead of an NSNumber or NSString.

Answer (score 0):

Use **NSMutableURLRequest** to send request and In Delegate Methods

```
    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
   {
     long expectedlength=[response expectedContentLength];
   }
```

I hope it will works..!